# Skip validation in some cases in Vee-Validate 3.0 using ValidationProvider

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I have a custom text input component which I wrapped in validation provider.

Basically it looks like this:

```
<validation-provider :rules="rules"
                     :vid="vid"
                     :name="name"
                     v-slot="{ errors, classes }"
                     slim>
  <div class="base-text-box"> ... </div>
</validation-provider>
```

Sometimes I need to validate it, however in some cases I don't need this. If I don't need validation I don't pass rules prop.

But how can I disable the provider when I don't need to validate my component? Couldn't find any related property in the docs.

Comment: just make `rules` string empty. no rules - no validation - no errors

Comment: also, you can pass rules as object, not string. for this case, rules looks like `{ required: true, email: true }` and then you can manipulate by some of rule just toggle  true-false value. in that case you need to create variable, for example, `isRequired` and pass it to your component

Comment: Tried to pass rules as 1) undefined 2) null 3) empty string, in all cases input get "valid" class in case of focus out event..:(

Comment: that's true behavior... I wrote "no rules - no validation - no errors". so that's why input is valid when you pass empty `rules`. this is your case as you wrote " disable the provider when I don't need to validate". if you want some logic else, please, clarify.

probably, you can play around construction `:class={'invalid': errors.length}` of `div` instead of usage `classes` inside `v-slot` object.

Answer (score 3):

This scrambled my brain too. The solution is to set the mode prop to passive.

You can also set the mode to a function if you need more flexibility.
https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/interaction-and-ux.html#interaction-modes

```
<ValidationProvider mode="passive" rules="required" v-slot="{ errors }">
  <!-- Some input -->
</ValidationProvider>
```